# Using hash as a bucket index, modulo vs bit-mask

Tags: hashtable, associative-array

I've been looking into hash tables, where some data is hashed and that is used for a bucket index.

Some libraries use the modulo of the hash with the bucket size, and others use a bit-mask.
Where only the bits used by the bucket mask are used (ensuring the range is not exceeded).

bitmask:

```
index = h->hash_func(key) & h->hash_mask;
```

modulo:

```
index = h->hash_func(key) % h->bucket_tot;
```

While there are obvious differences between the two, such as bucket size constraints with bit-masks, ensuring hashing gives good distribution on lower bits, speed of modulo... etc.

Are there strong reasons to choose one over another?

---

*(I'll probably try & benchmark for my own use-case, but curious whats already known on the matter).*

*Note, this is simply for key:value store, (dictionary/hash/associative-array) and **not** security related.*

Example of a dynamic resizing, chaining hash table implementation using bit-mask:

- https://github.com/amadvance/tommyds/blob/master/tommyds/tommyhashdyn.c
- https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/ghash.c

Example using modulo:

- https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/104887/sucinct-example-of-hash-table-w-chaining

Comment: Instead of asking generic and vague questions and complaining about answers, an perhaps more constructive approach would be answering your own questions with the reply you would like to see.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned "bucket" index so I assume you mean hash tables with separate chaining as collision resolution, in this case there is no reasons for using modulo or bit mask "stronger" that you mentioned (which BTW not so obvious, as you said).

In some languages, most notably Java/JVM-based, array index is positive signed 32-bit integer, thus maximum array size for bit mask is 2^30, that could be insufficient and a strong reason to use no-power-of-two table size and modulo, with which you can approach 2^31-1(max possible signed 32-bit integer)  very closely. But since you used C++ syntax this shouldn't be a concern for you.

Also, if you meant not only separate chaining, some open addressing collision resolution algorithms require table size to meet certain conditions, for example, if you implement double hashing, table size should be prime. In this case you obviously should use only modulo to obtain the initial index in the table.

Comment: Well, the max size of the bucket array is only one aspect. I would assume there are good reasons to choose one over another. Glib is a reasonably popular reason. maybe I need to ask the authors but would be curious to answer "Glib chose to use bitmasks to get the bucket index because '___'"

Comment: @ideasman42 short answer - because it is faster. It's what you mentioned as "speed of modulo".

Comment: Right, but there are other trade-offs. probably best I just test using a bitmask and see how it performs since there seems to be know real *best* choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't always just about performance either, sometimes it's about the domain of your problem.  You may, for example, have a mask that wishes to hash negative numbers as well.  With modulo you have to write special cases to handle them, not so with a bitmask.

Comment: In all cases where I've seen modulo used the hashes were unsigned ints, and even in the signed case you could simply cast to an unsigned value - it won't add any overhead in C/C++ for example.

Comment: In the cases you've seen domain of the problem is that the hashes used unsigned ints.  But for example in implementing, say, Perlin noise the function contains a valid range from -1 to 1.  In which case using a modulo simply requires a little extra work work.  I'm not saying one is better than the other but to answer the original question as to why.